# How do I schedule the rendering of a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

I would like to render a component on my react-app at a given time eg 6.00PM 27 October 2022. For example, a form would be released for signing up at that from that given time onward. This time stamp would be stored in my database, which will be queried by the react-app. How do I accomplish this in React with JavaScript?

I have thought of comparing Date() objects. Eg. get the current time and compare it to a Timestamp converted to Date() queried from the firebase firestore. However, I am unsure how I would use UseEffect to update the current time continuously for the comparison. Is this approach correct? If not, I would appreciate some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the current time to the stored timestamp and set a [*timeout*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) with the difference. In the timeout callback, toggle some state to display the component

```jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Scheduled = ({ timestamp, children }) => {
  const [isEnabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const diff = timestamp - Date.now();
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setEnabled(true);
    }, diff);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [timestamp]);

  return isEnabled ? <>{children}</> : null;
};
```

If the current time has passed the timestamp, this will show immediately.

You could then use this component like this

```jsx
<Scheduled timestamp={timestampFromDb}>
  <SomeFormComponent />
</Scheduled>
```

[image: Edit sweet-shape-m5qyyv]

Comment: diff is declared inside the `useEffect` hook, so this should throw an error shouldn't it? I think just timestamp should be a dependency.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton `timestamp` is already the dependency. There's no problem declaring variables inside the effect hook

Comment: oh my bad, misread

Comment: This is a good implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is for the component to be rendered without a page refresh, then you could use an interval within `useEffect` to the effect of

```js
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (new Date() > serverDate) {
      setVisible(true);
    }
  }, 10000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Change `10000` to whatever interval you want to check at.

Comment: This could be a good idea. However, wouldn't this also cause the checking to continue after the mounting of the component?